# French doors are falling apart and don't close

Tags: repair, doors

I have a pair of french doors in my place not much unlike these

[image]

The seams at the top of the door are coming apart and now they overlap when they shut and you have to open them both a bit, line them up, then close them together. If I push on the door toward the hinge - pretty much pushing the doors back together - they work for a few times.

Am I able to glue them back together? What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: The actual doors are falling apart, or the doors are sagging on their hinges?

Comment: It seem that the actual door is falling apart. I can see a space in the seams and when I push them back together, they close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the look, the easiest and least risky solution is to secure the door pieces with mending plates.  All you have to do is put the joints back together and pre drill the screw holes.
[image: mending strap]

Comment: There's room on the top of the door, so I won't see them at all. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the doors, this is speculation, but I'd probably want to pin the joints with approximately 12" long 5/8" dowels epoxied in. This assumes that the door is solid wood, not particle core with a veneer skin.

- remove doors
- square and clamp
- drill 2 holes per joint from the stiles with long auger bit. **The adventure here is that if you stray off center, you've destroyed your door.**
- epoxy in dowels, trim, apply protective finish.

This isn't rocket science, but it's high risk. You might consider new doors, as they aren't terribly expensive.